# Can anyone point me references that address the difficulty in defining what is mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, definition, math-history

I've been looking for some subjects, but I've found very little. Someone, is there some kind of subject that deals with the topic?

Comment: Have you already searched for the topic "philosophy of mathematics"? (Not that I have any specific recommendations to make in that area.)

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary.

Comment: Mathematics is what mathematicians do, which I guess is a kind of tautology but has a family resemblence to Duchamps quip 'art is what artists do' (and actually Chris Isham, a physicist made the same remark for physics but I don't know if he was referring to Duchamp though).

Comment: @MoziburUllah I think that the question then becomes, who is a mathematician ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I wasn't being entirely serious ;). I think Chris Isham went on to remark it was down to community/peer consensus; I guess the questioner is looking for a more objective answer.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I have it: Math is what they do on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I am a counterexample to that proposition. :)

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley: I think I might be too :).

Comment: Some relevant information can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2488092/72694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematics is the amusement of those who are much less interested in the meaning of certain symbols but are much more interested in the logic of the rules applicable on those mere symbols.

Comment: Tell that to Archimedes.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: I will.

Comment: There we go - question settled. Take that, Immanuel Kant! :)